# Calculate voltage with voltage divider

Tags: circuit-analysis, voltage-divider

[image]

I’m very confused when I have to find voltage at different resistors terminals. How do I do it? Series-parallel circuit.
For example v01 at R2 terminals and V02 at R4 terminals

Comment: Can you calculate the total current draw from the 12 V supply? Can you calculate how much current is flowing in each branch?

Comment: I know that the total current is 6A, I just used Ohms Law, But I thought I need to use voltage divider. Anyway, I dont know How to calculate current in each branch. do I need to use Kirchoff?

Comment: The total current will be 6mA = 0.006A not 6A. Yes, you need to use Kirchhoff's.

Comment: Of course, you can use voltage divider \$V_{01} = V_I \frac{R_2||(R_3 + R_4)}{R_1 + R_2||(R_3 + R_4} = 6V\$ and \$V_{02} = V_{01}\frac{R_4}{R_3 + R_4 } = 3V\$

Comment: Everything is a voltage divider if you allow difficult enough expressions, but in this case you could solve it as just voltage dividers. If I were your teacher, I wouldn’t mind. Please try.

Comment: So Basically V01 is R234 divided by the total resistance, and v02 is just a simple voltage divider that begins from v01

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can approach this from the right to the left using elemental voltage divider methods. Or set up two equations using KCL and solve that using [Cramer's rule](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cramer%27s_rule), if solving by hand or just using a solver, otherwise. And that's not the limit of approaches you can use, by any stretch.

Let's go from right backwards to the left.

On the right side, you have a voltage divider formed by \$R_3\$ and \$R_4\$. Here, \$V_{O_2}=V_{O_1}\cdot\frac1{1+\frac{R_3}{R_4}}\$ and its load impedance is \$R_{O_2}=R_3+R_4\$.

Next, you have a voltage divider formed by \$R_1\$ and \$R_2\$ but with an added load (in parallel with \$R_2\$) of \$R_{O_2}\$. So here, \$V_{O_1}=V_{I}\cdot\frac1{1+\frac{R_1}{R_2\,\vert\vert\, R_{O_2}}}\$.

So the complete symbolic-form answer is:

$$\begin{align*}
V_{O_1}&=V_{I}\cdot\frac1{1+\frac{R_1}{R_2\,\vert\vert\, \left(R_3+R_4\right)}}
\\\\
V_{O_2}&=V_{O_1}\cdot\frac1{1+\frac{R_3}{R_4}}=V_{I}\cdot\frac1{1+\frac{R_1}{R_2\,\vert\vert\, \left(R_3+R_4\right)}}\cdot\frac1{1+\frac{R_3}{R_4}}
\end{align*}$$

The main thing to note is that the right-side divider is itself unloaded, so it solves as a simple voltage divider problem, but that this right-side divider does load down the left-side divider, and that fact has to be accounted for when working out the left side.

In your approach, you find that the total load impedance is \$2\:\text{k}\Omega\$. If so, then you should recognize that the source current will be \$\frac{12\:\text{V}}{2\:\text{k}\Omega}=6\:\text{mA}\$. This means that \$R_1\$ must drop \$6\:\text{V}\$ across it, leaving \$V_{O_1}=6\:\text{V}\$. That current will equally split between \$R_2\$, which is \$2\:\text{k}\Omega\$ and the series pair, \$R_3+R_4=2\:\text{k}\Omega\$. So there will be \$3\:\text{mA}\$ through \$R_3+R_4\$ and each will drop exactly \$3\:\text{V}\$. So, \$V_{O_2}=3\:\text{V}\$. So, your approach works fine.

Answer (score 2):

Here's how I "see" such circuits:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fTCmY3.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Then

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fkD41K.png)</sup>

Ok, so VO1 is a mid-point of a 1k:1k voltage divider from 12V - so VO1=6V.

Now that we know VO1, we can use that fact:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fxMJWX.png)</sup>

Once we know VO1, we stick a voltage source in there - it reflects the potential present at that point in the circuit. **Adding this source to the original circuit changes nothing, since no current flows through that source**. VO1 is now held fixed at 6V by the source, and we can remove any components in parallel with that source - they don't change any voltages.

After removing R2, there then *is* a current flowing through VO1, but so what - it's an ideal voltage source. The voltage is fixed no matter the current. Then we're left with VO2 being is 6V divided down by another 1k:1k divider - and is 3V.

The values in this circuit were chosen *specifically* to facilitate the transformations I've performed above. It's not a coincidence that the numbers "work out" so nicely. It's by design in this case. That's what authors of teaching materials - be it textbooks or teachers - deal with :)

This circuit is a "cut down" version of the [R-2R ladder used in some DAC converters](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Resistor_ladder#R%E2%80%932R_resistor_ladder_network_(digital_to_analog_conversion)).

---

If you'd want to simulate the circuit, only *one* variant should be left, and the others removed from the schematic, since:

- SPICE disallows repeated reference designators, and
- the nodes labeled GND (triangle symbol), VO1 and VO2 are respectively connected together between the circuit variants as shown.

That's why simulation won't work as-is. But as soon as you delete two circuits that you don't care about from a simulation, and leave one left, everything will work as expected. CircuitLab does "dynamic" DC analysis - it shows DC operating point without having to run simulation. Just mouse over points in the circuit and voltages and/or currents will be displayed.

Comment: Thank you everyone for the answears!! It did clarify things for me